# What is this red thing on a Jurassic Park poster?

Tags: object-identification, jurassic-park

[image: Jurassic Park poster image]

I came across this Jurassic Park poster and I was puzzled by something I didn’t recognize. In the top right there’s a red shape peeking out from behind the Jurassic Park gate.

[image: close up view]

What is this red thing?

Comment: On the assumption that it's symmetrical, I've [mirrored the object and tried to remove the obstructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvhNi.png). I really can't make head nor tails of what it's supposed to be, but it sure as heck doesn't look like a DNA sequence.

Comment: https://cdn.prime1studio.com/media/magpleasure/mpblog/upload/4/8/48367edeb93e181c5aa7548ff367ff11.jpg

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E8vLQRlVkAMenNv?format=jpg&name=large

Comment: This product appears to have been commissioned by Prime1Studio. I've asked their customer service the question.

Comment: I just watched the orientation video/ride scene in the movie, and it doesn't appear there. It seems to have the same visual characteristics as "Mr. DNA" on the other side, so I'm guessing it's supposed to be a cartoony representation of a DNA sequence.

Comment: After some consideration on the subject, I'm wondering if it's a Jurassic Park gas-powered jeep, seen from an odd angle (possible from above, looking down). https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/Kb4AAOSwqK9fPDI8/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: Better questions would be, "what's the cartoon on the other side, and why did the artist decide to break the 'tone' of the poster by adding cartoon graphics?"

Comment: @RonJohn the cartoon character on the right is "Mr. DNA", as mentioned in Omegacron's comment. There is a whole cartoon sequence in the movie where Mr. DNA explains how dinosaurs are made from DNA found in mosquitos trapped in amber. I had forgotten this until I looked it up just now.

Comment: Looks like a Space Invader to me.

Comment: This is probably _way_ off base, but the studio (per @Valorum) is called Prime1, and that doesn't half look like like an 8-bit Optimus Prime peeking round the edge of the gate. I agree it's probably really a DNA sequence but that's one Hell of a coincidence.

Comment: @Spratty - I did think about that, but it's nothing like their logo, the company doesn't have any affiliation with Optimus Prime and there's no other similar cameos in other posters by the same company and artist.

Comment: @Valorum - like I said, _way_ off base, but the coincidence was just too much for me (my younger brother was obsessed with the original Transformers cartoon series and I saw way too much of Optimus and co. back then). Also, your research efforts put mine ("hey, that looks a bit like Optimus Prime, if you're not too fussy!") to shame :-)

Answer (score 39):

Fitting with the theme of genetic manipulation and the corresponding character to the left of the gates, it appears to be a cartoon version of a DNA [chromatograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatography):

[image]

<sup>[Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Olga-Zelenaia/publication/23403270/figure/fig4/AS:279113681129509@1443557295445/Characterization-of-DNA-impurities-a-Total-DNA-was-isolated-from-fractions-obtained.png) Fair usage 2021</sup>

Comment: Too fast for me

Comment: Could be, but it seems like an odd choice. I don't see a lot of chromatographs associated with Jurassic Park.

Comment: Strictly speaking those are images of gel electrophoresis, which is not a chromatographic method. Not that I disagree with your answer, especially given the cartoon DNA (RNA? protein?) on the other side of the gates.

Comment: @bob1: That cartoon character is Mr. DNA, from the still-unfinished pop-sci short film that John Hammond shows to the other main characters at the visitor centre (as a demo of the ride/show guests will see), at 0:24:52 in the movie.  The part of that short included in that scene didn't include the rectangular red graphics from the top right of the poster, but I'd guess they appear on-screen somewhere else in the movie.

Answer (score 23):

**DNA sequence**
I'm not a scientist so this might not be the right term but it looks like uncoiled DNA strands as a lab result.
It is also opposite Mr. DNA on the image.

Here is a stock image of test tubes and a DNA sequence in the background.
[image: stock image of test tubes and a DNA]

**EDIT:**
[Karyotype.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karyotype)  Explains the unevenness and more clearly illustrates the bands.

[image: Karyotype of Human genome]

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Prime Studio, who commissioned this artwork for their 2021 '[Jurassic World Gallery 2021](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E8vLQRlVkAMenNv?format=jpg&name=large)' collection of merchandise. They had this to say on the subject;

> Q. Can I ask if that red design is suppose to *represent* something (like a DNA fingerprint for example)?
>
> A.Exactly, **the texture is a design that represents the DNA fingerprint in a figurative way.**
>
> <sub><sup>Edited for clarity</sup></sub>

Comment: That response from Prime Studio is, I feel, an answer from someone who doesn't know, as they didn't have the answer or anyone who had the answer to hand. I think if they had directly contacted the artist(s) responsible, they would have given the same answer as @ARogueAnt in that it is stylised DNA chromatography, or at least a "texture design" based on that. The similarity is too strong for it to be a coincidence.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - And we have our answer. Notably the artist was their "in-house art team" so it looks like there wasn't a single artist that worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

While rewatching the movie, the only visually similar thing I noticed were the banks of red lights in the control room.

[image]

Comment: They're red, but that's about the only thing that's similar about them.